# HD 4800 lower fan speed

Tags: kernel, xorg, drivers, fan

I've installed Linux Mint 17, most important thing for me is to lower the fan speed to 30% as I am doing in Windows because it's really too noisy. Note that the temperature stays at ~50°, so this shouldn't be a heating issue.

The problem is the only drivers available are for Xorg 6.9 to Xserver 1.12 and Kernel version up to 3.4 to the latest.

Is there a way to reduce fan speed without installing ATI drivers?

I was doing it before by using the command `aticonfig`.

I have an ATI HD 4870, 512MB on a desktop computer.

My scaling governor is set to 'ondemand':

```
$ cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor
ondemand
```

Comment: Why bother? That's not a solution, i want a real solution. Like modify a line somewhere to reduce my fan speed as it is possible with ati drivers. Cleaning dust won't solve anything. It is not even 50*C in Aida64.

Comment: That's the kind of detail we need to know. I added the temperature to your question. For all I know, you have a system running at 80 degrees and want to bring down the fan. It is usually not a good idea to do so but I agree, if it's running at 50, it sounds like the kernel is not regulating it correctly. I deleted the now obsolete comments.